# How to respond with react app in only one route using expressjs?

Tags: reactjs, express

So i have a client and server directory, client has a react app, and server has express file, and ejs templates. I want to render these ejs templates when get request to "/" and "/login" which i have done and I want to respond with the react app only when get request to "/submit". But after building the app, it automatically renders in "/" as well as "/submit". I also could only use styles of react app. I also have some styles for my ejs templates.
Here is my code:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const app= express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
//have to comment this to work, but ejs styles not work app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/build')));

app.get('/submit', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/build', 'index.html'));
});

app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
  res.render("home");
});

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log("Server started on " + PORT);
});
```

So i have two problems:

1. How to have two express.static?
   2)How to serve react app only in one route that is not the root route?

I tried adding homepage field
`"homepage":"localhost:3001/submit"`
in the package.json file in client directory with the react app, it didn't work. Both the root and /submit route display error `The resource from “http://localhost:3001/test/static/js/main.fe8416d4.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).`
When i removed /submit from
`script defer="defer" src="submit/static/js/main.fe8416d4.js"></script>`
it worked but in both root and /submit route